# secured pages in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, security, authorization

config I have :

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode ="Forms">
        <forms name ="loginpage" loginUrl="login_to_secure3700.aspx" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
<location path ="securedpages/bob.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This way the pag bob.aspx will only be accessible when the username and password were entered ok.
BUT , this works only for page bob.aspx, how can I make this work for eg 50 pages, but all with different logins and passwords. ?

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? Create a website that is different for different users or individual pages for individual people?

Comment: creating a website that has a one login page for 50 clients, as soon as they enter their login and password it should redirect them to their personalized page. eg if bob logs in , bob.aspx opens up. if jonas logs in, jonas.aspx opens. but when jonas logs in he cannot open bob.aspx .

Comment: What is different in the content. I would personally use one page that is protected and change the content dynamically based on the username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

Secure each page with deny all users and only allow bob on bob.aspx and helen to helen.aspx. Given the answers above you will manage that fore sure but it is cumbersume: for every new user you need to change your config.

I think the better way is to create one! page (user.aspx) and take the user that is logged in and personalize that single page for this user. This is a lot easier to maintain and you will have all the code on one page.

If you want to keep the personalized approach in the pagename (bob.aspx) you can have a look into URL rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

You could add multiple paths like this:

```
<location path ="securedpages/bob.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path ="securedpages/bob2.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Or more simple, just add the dir of the secured pages:

```
<location path ="securedpages">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: the second approach will not work in this particular case. +1 for the first approach

Answer (score 0):

you can put all the 50 pages in one folder and the add 1 web.config for them in this folder that contains

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

It does not matter if they have different logins and password.

Comment: will not work since bob can also view jonas' page in this case